# Cocos2D Touch HELP

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I`m new to cocos2d library, I worked before with libgdx and pure openGL. How can I handle a touch event in Cocos2d for Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4 methods for handling touches on android are defined as follows:

```
public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event);

public boolean ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent event);

public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event);

public boolean ccTouchesCancelled(MotionEvent event);
```

These are the listeners you should use.

And also add below line in constructor of your CCLayer class to enable touch event.

```
this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
```

Comment: any reason that these functions are not firing ?

Answer (score 0):

To start touch event you have to first to set variable

```
isTouchEnabled_=true;
```

or

```
setIsTouchEnabled(true);
```

After that touch will work

You can use methods as:-

```
  @Override
      public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event) {
}
      @Override
    public boolean ccTouchesMoved(MotionEvent event) {
}

      @Override
        public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event) {
}
      @Override
      public boolean ccTouchesCancelled(MotionEvent event) {
}
```

I have used this like as in CCColorLayer:-

```
protected GameLayer(ccColor4B color) {
        super(color);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        isTouchEnabled_=true;
}

      @Override
          public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event) {
    }
```